# private apk file for android?

Tags: android, apk

```
i have to create an apk with key and publish it.
```

And public can decode that apk file by apktool and dex2jar.
Please help me how to create my private apk that can not be decode by other person by apktool and dex2jar.
Provide me link or proper solution. thanks in advance..

Comment: You are looking for this: [How to avoid reverse engineering of an APK file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854425/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-an-apk-file)

Answer (score 0):

you can set it in to eclipse environment by right clicking on your project, and choose Android tool -> Export signed application package option and then do as your need

Hope It will work

Comment: I think Question is saying "It can't be decode by other person by using APKTool or dex2jar.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is you can decode any type of apk file when it's been installed in phone. you can back up and use it. you can decode it and extract it. AndroidSuite is a powerful tool that decode any type of apk and also encode resource files etc. So as far as I know, it's a tedious process.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1461135

My suggestion is to prevent extracting apk from phone is use "File observer.java" to monitor whether apk been backed up,if so do some stuff to delete where it gets stored.