# Disable taking apk file from an installed android application

Tags: java, android, google-play

Usually it is possible to take .apk file of an android application even after it is installed in a device. But I could find some applications, which are protected from taking their .apk files.

As it is also possible to extract code from the .apk file, I think the developers code is not safe. Can anybody tell me how can I prevent a third party from taking .apk file of my android application?

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 0):

As for not having the possibility to take the APK, I don't think you can really prevent it since eventually it is only a file located somewhere in the internal storage. As long as the user has enough permissions he can extract it.

Protecting the code. There are several levels of protection but eventually, you cannot prevent it 
If you do nothing, the reverse engineering of the code is pretty simple.
There are several tools to obtain some level of security.
For example, [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html), which is a Google's tool which already built in in most Android IDEs.

An excellent SO post for code protection:
[How to avoid reverse engineering of an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854425/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-an-apk-file)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lior Ohana. But i could find some applications which is in the locked state. for example Instagram, Skype, Viber, etc. It is not possible to take a backup of these applications. How can I achieve that kind of lock?

Comment: NP. I know some apps are not allowed for some backup/export apps. What I meant was that eventually, on a rooted device, you can just open a shell console and grab the APK.
If all you're talking about is having the minimal protection of the apps you describe than it might be possible. I'll do some investigation and update if I'll find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I was investigating this issue and thought I will update here. It is recommended for security reasons that you set this in your android manifest file:

`android:allowBackup="false"`

So, if somebody tries to do a full adb system backup or uses it to backup your app in particular, it won't come in the backup, thus preventing them to extract the apk from there. I tested this and it works, i.e. the adb backup didn't allow backup of my sample app.

Then I installed an app for taking app backups (ES File explorer), and unfortunately, it allowed the .apk backup to be taken for my sample app where backup was disabled. And this was an unrooted device. This seems to indicate that setting this property in manifest doesn't prevent other apps to take backups.

So there are few options left:

1. Use proguard and other best practices to make it difficult to reverse engineer your apps.
2. Use app licensing keys provided as a service by Google Play to avoid piracy of your app.

Comment: `android:allowBackups="false"` doesn't stop someone from copying your apk, it just destroys user data by preventing it from being backed up.

Comment: `android:allowBackup` just say Android to automatically backup app data or don't. See here for more info: [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html#EnablingAutoBackup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html#EnablingAutoBackup) @raghum