# How can i prevent my app from decompiling it to java code

Tags: android

I was reading this article about decompilation of .apk file into java code...my question is  how can i prevent it from decompilation?
[here is the link of that article](http://a4apphack.com/security/sec-code/extract-android-apk-from-market-and-decompile-it-to-java-source)

Comment: use proguard to obfuscate your code which will make it hard to reverse engineer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html.

Enable proguard in release mode

The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer.

Also check the answer by commonsware in the below link

[How to avoid reverse engineering of an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854425/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-an-apk-file/13854693#13854693)

here's an example

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html