# How to protect .apk file from being read

Tags: android, cordova, encryption, google-play

Since it is easy to extract and read an **.apk file**, I want to understand If I upload a android project .apk file in **Google play**, and when a user downloads the application, the apk file gets downloaded on this temp folder of the phone memory. Is there a way the user can read the code in the apk file ?

If yes, what should be my considerations to protect/encrypt the apk downloaded on the users phone from **Google play** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid reverse engineering of an APK file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854425/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-an-apk-file)

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi is it the same for other stores, example for apple ? or i think apple does not allow to view the files download on the device

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi another question, is it the same if we develop an app using phonegap ?

Comment: I have never use phonegap

Answer (score 1):

To increase security How about applying ProGuard http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html