# how to avoid reverse engineering APK file and secure by hiding or encrypting the class files

Tags: android

I have developed an Android Application which is more valuable, now I want to secure by hiding or encrypting class files, so that no developer can Reverse engineering from APK file, from following link: http://www.javadecompilers.com/

Please give me the solution, by any example.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854425/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-an-apk-file

Comment: I have gone through it already, but I need steps to Use Proguard, in my project to encrypt at least some selected functions

Answer (score 0):

you can choose the release variant from the Build Variants view and build it from the GUI:[image]

now please take a look for Your configuration build.gradle file for proguard implementation. It can be module level or the project level.

```
buildTypes {

  debug {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-  
    rules.txt'

  }
}
```

The configuration shown is for debug level you can write your own build scripts like shown below inside buildTypes:

```
myproductionbuild{
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-
    rules.txt'
}
```

Better to have your dedug with minifyEnabled false and productionbuild and other builds as minifyEnabled true .

Answer (score 0):

Completely avoiding reverse engineering an android application is highly unlikely but you can use proguard to obfuscate code or use a sdk solution like appvigil, quixxi or arxan for full fledged security. Code obfuscation will make code readability challenging but there is a possibility that a hacker can understand the app or business logic. To prevent this you can use dynamic loading of libraries. You can create separate jar or dex and load them into your application when needed, call functions in jar/ dex using reflections.