# After unzipping the signed apk, all the assets are shown. Is this expected?

Tags: android, cordova, security

I have created an app using Cordova, After doing release signed apk,

When I unzip the apk, It is showing all assets like index.html and my custom JS.

Is there any way to restrict it?

Comment: Yeah. That is totally normal.

Answer (score 0):

An APK file is basically a ZIP file and all the assets are visible to everybody. Therefore if you use techniques like hybrid apps (Cordova) all your JavaScript code is directly accessible.

There is only one way to "prevent" (or to be realistic it is more "complicate access") access to the resources:

Buy an APK protection tool that includes resource encryption (e.g. DexProtector or something similar).

See also 
[How to avoid reverse engineering of an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854425/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-an-apk-file)