# How to protect android source code

Tags: android

In android How to protect android source code while uploading app in to playstore, I'm using progaurd then also we can extract code through APK Decompiler

```
 buildTypes {
    release {

        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't protect your code from reverse engineering to 100%.
What you can do is make it harder for a hacker to change your code though.

You can also follow some of these steps mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854425/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-an-apk-file) to avoid security issues.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

After doing Reverse Engineering in many application. I got the point that to secure your application use all string value, network call URLs in `string.xml` file. Your `class` files convert into `java` file. And resources got encrypted in other file.

You can use [proguard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) to shrink your code and resources.

Comment: that is good. really good. But as you have one real application in playstore. Just for one time do reverse engineering in your application. It will help you to improve your code in better way

Answer (score 2):

Well actually we will ***never*** get 100% security on our code. But we can do some stuff to make the life of a potential malicious user a little bit more difficult:

Optimizing and obfuscating the code with [**ProGuard**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) it this first step to take which works with byte code targeted at Android's Dalvik VM.

Also Proguard it's the suggested method by the official docs, and it ships along with the SDK Tools since **Android 2.3**

> Integrated ProGuard support: ProGuard is now packaged with the SDK
> Tools. Developers can now obfuscate their code as an integrated part
> of a release build.

### Suggested readings

[**Proguard, Android, and the Licensing Server**](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2010/09/proguard-android-and-licensing-server.html)

[**Securing Android LVL Applications**](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2010/09/securing-android-lvl-applications.html)