# reverse engineering protection

Tags: android, security, apk, reverse-engineering

I read in a sample of the book Decompiling Android by Nolan Godfrey that the usage of `goto` method can make the source code produce non readable code when decompiling the apk.

The `goto` method is unused in Java though..So how can someone make use of this?

Are there any other methods someone can use to make the decompiled
code non readable?

(Please do not comment or answer that no matter what I do the CIA will always be able to fully reverse my app. And obviously I'm past the point of using Proguard, etc).

Comment: "Are there any other methods someone can use to make the decompiled code non readable ?" -- that's not possible. If the app can be run, the app can be read. At best, you might be able to cause specific versions of specific decompilers to produce output that is more difficult for some people to read. Also, that portion of your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13854425/115145) and probably many others.  "I read in a sample" -- that's a five-year-old book; my guess is that decompilers have overcome whatever the `goto` trick was.

Comment: It doesn't take the CIA to reverse engineer a Proguarded app. Just a motivated hacker.

Comment: It is recommended to ask questions about Reverse Engineering in [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can try ProGuard for basic protection, or DexGuard for full protection and encryption: https://www.guardsquare.com/en/dexguard

Comparision: https://www.guardsquare.com/en/blog/dexguard-vs-proguard

However, on larger project using many external libs, configuration may be not straighforward