# Gradle.Property Values showin in Decompile APK

Tags: android, android-studio

Today i tried and decompile my product apk and seen the values which i defined in gradle.properties. I really shock, my authentication details shown to everyone like when some body try to decompile my product apk.

Any guess and ideas how will protect those information from others.
In My product - i am using some slat key / htaccess username and password. Those details wants to protect from others.

Suggestion pls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid reverse engineering of an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854425/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-an-apk-file)

Comment: would you please tell in which file you were seeing it in decompiled app? does it go to strings.xml?

Comment: How did you decompile? I have tried and could not find gradle.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use proGuard to protect your source code against decompiling.
you can read about it here: [proGuard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)

For storing your users informations like usernames and passwords you can use firebase authentication . I believe it is the most powerful and secure way to store such informations. You can also read about it here:
[firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/?gclid=Cj0KCQjw3InYBRCLARIsAG6bfMTnyu4Rzi7j6os3BD25R0j0B4WXgfgPQzuLZ86evC4qgG0Bzg3X4LAaAsdCEALw_wcB)