# Proguard for retrofit url

Tags: android, proguard

I have to secure my code from reverse engineering. Also I need to hide the Web Service URL I'm using in my app. 
I have created a interface and declared all the URLs in a static variable.
Can anyone help me how can I obfuscate my interface class variables and methods so that they are not decoded from the tools available from online.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid reverse engineering of an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854425/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-an-apk-file)

Comment: Why you have to hide the Web Service URL? Proguard/R8 are not obfuscating strings inside your app.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fully protect urls through obfuscation but you can make extra layer for security by using NDK, storing urls in native C/C++ file and accessing them in our Java classes. Unlilke java code C/C++ code can’t be decompiled, it can be only disassembled.