# How do I make my paid application that I published on Google Play not allowed to be installed outside

Tags: java, android-studio, security

How do I make my paid application on Google Play not allowed to be installed outside Google Play or to take a copy of it such as an Apk and install it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent someone to take your APK and install it.

The things you can try to do would be :

Prevent the Reverse Engineering by protecting your APK :
[Please read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854425/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-an-apk-file)

Also, you can control group of user who will be able to download your app with the [play store private channel feature](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en)